# Having trouble running virtual env synced on work machine

Tags: python, environment-variables, sublimetext, virtual

I use sublime text + virtualenv and dropbox to create a simple dev environment that i can keep with synced settings across two machines.

Works flawlessly on one but not the other, it gives me this error.

I know the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'" is because it's not able to load the environment since that specific env has all the required modules, must be something with the reference to that env or such but i can't seem to figure it out. Appreciate your help!

I tried reinstalling virtual env loader module in sublime text

I could give a code example but this happens with anything i try to run even just a print(10) statement

Here is the debug error results:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000000010e37a5c0 (most recent call first):
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code -6]
[cmd: ['/bin/bash', '-c', 'python -u "/Users/kashour/Dropbox (Personal)/Reference/Coding/Environment/python.py"']]
[dir: /Users/kashour/Dropbox (Personal)/Reference/Coding/Environment]
[path: /opt/facebook/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public/:/opt/facebook/bin/biggrep:/opt/facebook/nuclide/latest/nuclide/pkg/fb-on-demand-cli/bin:/opt/facebook/ops/scripts/chef:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/munki:/opt/facebook/hg/bin:/opt/X11/bin]
```

Comment: You could give the required code example but you won't? Not if you don't want your question closed.  [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

When you create a virtualenv it's essentially an extension of the python distribution you created it with, it's linked to your installation of python on your host system. So when you create the virtualenv on the original system, it links against the systems installation of python. When you moved the virtualenv to another machine, it's not finding the python installation that it was originally linked against.

virtualenv is not portable across systems, and it's not a complete portable python runtime, it's simply a way to isolate an environment for a specific context, for instance to solve dependency version differences between different applications that you're using / working on.